# Swift: Cannot assign to the result of the expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am upgrading my Objective-C code to Swift. I want to update the frame based on the image size like below:

```
let imageViewFrame: CGRect = view.frame
if (image.size.width <= image.size.height) {
     imageViewFrame.origin.x = (view.frame.size.width - view.frame.size.height)/4
     imageViewFrame.size.width = view.frame.size.height
}
```

here I am getting an error saying: "Cannot assign to the result of the expression"
what I should do to remove the error?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It's the `imageViewFrame.size.width = view.frame.size.height` line that has the error, right?

Comment: both the lines inside the if statement

Answer (score 27):

You're declaring `imageViewFrame` using `let` which makes it immutable.

You could use `var` instead of `let` for `imageViewFrame` which would make it mutable.

```
var imageViewFrame: CGRect = view.frame
```